# ERROR: Loading module scapy.layers.ipsec from cryptography.utils import CryptographyDeprecationWarning

Tags: scapy

I get the following when running scapy in Gradescope

> ERROR: Loading module scapy.layers.ipsec
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scapy/main.py", line 156, in _load
> mod = importlib.import_module(module)
> File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/**init**.py", line 126, in import_module
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
> File "", line 994, in _gcd_import
> File "", line 971, in _find_and_load
> File "", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "", line 665, in _load_unlocked
> File "", line 678, in exec_module
> File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scapy/layers/ipsec.py", line 519, in 
> from cryptography.utils import CryptographyDeprecationWarning
> ImportError: cannot import name 'CryptographyDeprecationWarning'

None of the suggested workarounds fix this and the reported fixed does not get installed.
I need to install scapy via

> apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip python3-dev

> pip3 install scapy

As i am running this in gradescope.  Would really like to get rid of this

I have tried all the published workarounds regarding muting warnings - they did not work